# How can I remove all whitespaces in php codes?

Tags: php

I have an application that built and run in PHP codes. And hundreds of **whitespaces** (such as tab space, more than one spaces and line breaks) that I've written during my development and I want to publish it in production. Is there an available **tool** or **application** that could trim my codes?

Comment: And you are looking to achieve this using... `jQuery`?

Comment: http://beta.phpformatter.com/

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly. Remove all white-space characters in php files? If so: Why?

Comment: Tiny PHP: http://labs.builtbyprime.com/tinyphp/

Comment: Would whitespaces affects the page download in client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any Online PHP formatter as suggested by Jack in comments i.e; http://beta.phpformatter.com/

OR use any IDE which provides such feature, I use PHPStorm and it provides auto formatting for this.

Comment: Not fully get what I want but it could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use online tools for compressing your codes